# How can I stop ASP.NET Menu controls from generating inline html style elements

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page that contains an ASP.NET server side Menu control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu)

I *am* using the CSSFriendly adapters from here

http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/Menu.aspx

and they do make the rendered HTML much cleaner however I am still getting inline styles output into the HEAD element in the HTML like this

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ctl00_SiteHeader1_TabBar1_Menu1_0 { background-color:white;visibility:hidden;display:none;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px; }
    .ctl00_SiteHeader1_TabBar1_Menu1_1 { text-decoration:none; }
    .ctl00_SiteHeader1_TabBar1_Menu1_2 {  }
    .ctl00_LeftColumnContent_LeftHandNavigator1_Menu1_0 { text-decoration:none; }

</style>
</head>

<body>
```

I thik these styles are being generated by ASP.NET, I don't think I need them as I am using the CSSAdapters so is there any way of stopping them from being generated?

Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short story is that it isn't [easily](http://forums.asp.net/p/1006669/1336527.aspx) accomplished. That code is added to the header by the menu during the prerender phase.

A possible workaround might be overriding the menu's onprerender in a custom menu control and don't call base. You could then replace the default menu control with your own using [tagMappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164641.aspx).

I'd suggest you stay clear of the menu control if you can.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET Framework 4, ASP.NET menu has a new property, `IncludeStyleBlock`, that you can set to false to avoid generation of `<style>` block. However, it still generates a `style="float:left"` attribute that can only be overridden with a `float: none !important` in your stylesheet.